# Use grizzly portunif to serve http and rpc in same port

Tags: java, rest, jersey, grizzly

I am using jersey on grizzly as a REST service, and it's required to compatible with legacy RPC-based client in same port.

I have tried grizzly portunif, but it seems grizzly 2.3+ removed HttpProtocolFinder.

Is there any suggestion or example?

Answer (score 1):

We'll restore HttpProtocolFinder in Grizzly 2.3.12, for now you can find its source code [here](https://github.com/GrizzlyNIO/grizzly-mirror/blob/2.3.x/modules/portunif/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/portunif/finders/HttpProtocolFinder.java).